# What's a good mnemonic for shell double vs. single quotes?

Tags: shell, scripting, quoting

I don't do enough scripting to remember, without looking up, whether double or single quotes result in a Unix variable being substituted.

I definitely understand **what is** going on. My question is does anyone have a **memory trick** for making the correct quoting rule stick in my head?

Comment: Use `rc` as your shell, then you have only one type of quotes (`"` is an ordinary character in `rc` where the only quotes are single quotes and backslash is only used for line-continuation (not  inside single quotes)). It's also got a much leaner, cleaner, better, more intuitive syntax and design than Korn-like shells like bash.

Comment: Learn Perl. Then you just have to memorize that shell behaves similar.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

*Single* quotes are *simple* quotes, with a *single* standard: every character is literal.
*Double* quotes have a *double* standard: some characters are literal, others are still interpreted unless there's a backslash before them.

*Single* quotes work alone: backslash inside single quotes is not special.
*Double* quotes pair up with backslash: backslash inside double quotes makes the next character non-special.

Comment: This is quite poetic. With a good editor (in the literary sense), we could make a children's book out of this. ["If You Teach a Snake to Script"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Give_a_Mouse_a_Cookie#If_You_Give..._series)

Comment: I've been trying to turn _Single quotes are simple quotes, with a single standard_ into a [Dr. Seuss style poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Seuss#Poetic_meters) for twenty minutes, and failing miserably.

Comment: Single quotes are single use, and lit'rally repeat / 
Double quotes are more verbose, a paramat'rising feat

Comment: @glennjackman [A FORTRAN colouring book](https://archive.org/stream/9780262610261)

Answer (score 7):

Double-quotes (`"`) are *weak* quotes- you need two of them, so they come in pairs, and variables punch right through them despite their numbers.

Single-quotes (`'`) are *strong* quotes- they come singly, and variables are no match for them.

Answer (score 6):

> "Double, double toil and trouble; 
> Dollars burn, and backquotes bubble."

Single, in contrast, is harmless.

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes, double fun!
Parameters are expanded
One by one.

Comment: If you write 'Params expanded one by one' it fixes the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Double-quotes (`"`) don't exactly mean what the say, for example a tool that says `"quality" equipment` is probably the opposite.

Single-quotes(`'`) are strong quotes, what is between them is exactly what it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Singular in purpose are they
Quotations that are single.

Treat literal the chars within
No matter how they mingle.

(T'is just one small rule you must know
Single quote within? No go!)

---

There are those quotes that are double
Inside which some chars may be trouble
Dollar, back-ticks and back-slash
Are treated special by Bash
Escaping, though, will burst that bubble.

Answer (score 1):

One: winter, as is
Two: summer, transformations
Forbid or allow