# How to use find command with variables

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, variable

I am searching for files by `find`ing a partial file name:

```
find /script -name '*file_topicv*'
/script/VER_file_topicv_32.2.212.1
```

It works, but not when the partial file name is a variable:

```
var=file_topicv
```

`find` reported file not found, (in spite of the file existing):

```
find /script -name '*$var*'
```

What is wrong here?

---

I also tried these:

```
find /script -name "*$var*"
find /script -name "*\$var*"
find /script -name "*\\$var*"
```

but not one of those works.

---

Update:

I think this is the problem:

```
var=` find /tmp -name '*.xml' -exec sed -n 's/<Name>\([^<]*\)<\/Name>/\1/p' {} +  |  xargs `

echo $var
generateFMN

ls  /script/VERSIONS | grep "$var"

NO OUTPUT

var=generateFMN
 ls  /script/VERSIONS | grep "$var"
VER_generateFMN_32.2.212.1
```

So why `$var` from `find` command cause the problem? (I removed the spaces by `xargs`.)

Comment: The first double-quoted one didn’t work?

Comment: no its not works

Comment: Single/double quotes difference: [What's a good mnemonic for shell double vs. single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400447/whats-a-good-mnemonic-for-shell-double-vs-single-quotes/400449), [BashGuide Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: ok , but why my options are not working ?

Comment: what version of bash are you running?   `bash --version | head -1`

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: instead of `echo $var`, try `printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed -n l` so you can really see what it contains.

Comment: @yael, do something like `echo "$var" | od -c`, or `printf "%q\n" "$var"` to see what actually goes to `var`.

Comment: @yael, also _please_ don't change your question after presenting, but _give the context up front_, it makes it much easier to answer the question you need an answer for...

Comment: I get this --> printf "%q\n" "$var"  then I get -->    $'generateFMN\r'

Comment: why $'generateFMN\r'  ?? instead to get generateFMN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first double-quoted one should work:

```
$ touch asdfghjkl
$ var=fgh
$ find -name "*$var*"
./asdfghjkl
```

Within single quotes (`'*$var*'`), the variable is not expanded, and neither is it expanded when the dollar sign is escaped in double quotes (`"*\$var*"`). If you double-escape the dollar sign (`"*\\$var*"`), the variable is expanded but `find` gets a literal backslash, too. (But `find` seems to take the backslash as an escape again, so it doesn't change the meaning.)

So, confusing though as it is, this also works:

```
$ set -x
$ find -name "*\\$var*"
+ find -name '*\fgh*'
./asdfghjkl
```

You can try to run all the others with `set -x` enabled to see what arguments `find` actually gets.

As usual, wrap the variable name in braces `{}`, if it's to be followed by letters, digits or underscores, e.g. `"*${prefix}somename*"`.

Comment: the first double-quoted one also works for me.   btw, worth mentioning that it will sometimes be necessary to use `${var}` rather than just `$var` inside the double-quotes, depending on what comes after the variable....a `*` is fine, a letter/digit/underscore/etc is not.

Comment: see my update , this is the problem , when $var comes from find & this isnt works

Comment: @yael It still works for me with `var=$(find ...)`.   The problem seems to be that something is adding a carriage-return `\r` to the string.  Or maybe it's in the input XML file already (maybe try `grep '<Name>' yourxmlfile | hexdump -C` and see if there's n `0D` byte in there).

Comment: @cas, they almost certainly have a CR in there, the sed here won't remove it or any other trailing garbage on the line. yael posted another question on it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417756/variable-printed-the-same-value-but-actually-value-is-diff