# variable printed the same value but actually value is diff

Tags: linux, shell-script, variable, string, test

the follwing syntax used in order to capture the word between  in xml file 
I also use xargs to remove any spaces

```
var=` find /tmp -name '*.xml' -exec sed -n 's/<Name>\([^<]*\)<\/Name>/\1/p' {} +  |  xargs `

echo $var
TOPIC
```

until now seems be ok

but printf show something else

```
printf "%q\n" "$var"
$'TOPIC\r'
```

lets drill down

```
[[ TOPIC == $var ]] && echo they are equal
```

**no printed "they are equal**

but when we print $var we get

```
echo $var
TOPIC
```

so after things looks clearly

the BIG BIG question is:

how to   remove the extra characters ($ , \r ) from variable -

```
$'TOPIC\r'
```

Comment: Actually, the BIG BIG question is why aren't you using an XML parser to parse XML? (Include a subtree from your XML and you'll get at least one solution that parses it properly.)

Comment: I cant install them , these are machines under customer responsible so you are right but in this case we not have choice only to use what is defined on the linux machines

Comment: can you move forward , how we can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do the customer machines already have an XML parsing tool installed? For example, my preferred is `xmlstarlet` but there are several others equally suitable.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1195001) it's like the most basic thing and if you can't then good luck it will be more than hard

Comment: @Kiwy not useful if the OP doesn't have any XML parser available

Comment: Actually, the BIG BIG question is why you aren't quoting your variables yet: `echo "$var"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `$'TOPIC\r'` is a visual representation given by your `printf` implementation to represent the content of that variable. It uses ksh93's `$'...'` form of quoting (now also supported by `zsh`, `bash` and a few other shells) to give you that representation. In those shells, `var=$'TOPIC\r'` would create a `$var` variable with that same content. In that form of quoting, `\r` represents a carriage return character.

That's a character which when sent to a terminal makes the terminal move the cursor to the beginning of the line. It's a control character for the terminal, it's not a normal character with a glyph associated to it.

```
printf 'ABC\rX\n'
```

(`printf`, in its *format* argument also recognises `\r` as meaning a CR character) is displayed as:

```
XBC
```

If you write:

```
printf 'ABC\rX\n' | pv -qL3
```

to slow it down, you can see what happens.

To remove it, with ksh93-like shells (ksh93, zsh, bash or mksh), you can do

```
var=${var//$'\r'}
```

`\r` is also classified as a `[:space:]` character. So you can also remove all spacing characters with:

```
var=${var//[[:space:]]}
```

To remove only that CR character (the one at the end of the variable):

```
var=${var%$'\r'}
```

(which should be portable to a few more shells).

POSIXly (like in portable `sh` scripts), you can do:

```
var=$(printf %s "$var" | tr -d '\r')
```

Though note that it would also remove newline (aka linefeed aka LF aka `\n`) characters off the end of the content of the variable.

As a side note, `[[ TOPIC = $var ]]`  (also a `ksh`ism also supported by zsh and bash) is a pattern matching operator, not an equality testing operator (except in `zsh` when not emulating ksh/bash), you need `[[ TOPIC = "$var" ]]` to test for equality, `var=*; [[ TOPIC = $var ]]` would return *true* for instance (and `var='[x]'; [[ $var = $var ]]` would return *false*).

Also remember that [`echo` cannot be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803) and [parameter expansions should generally be quoted](/q/171346).

```
$ var=$'TOPIC\r'
$ printf '%s\n' "$var" # zsh (my shell) builtin
TOPIC
$ printf '%q\n' "$var"
TOPIC$'\r'
$ /usr/bin/printf '%q\n' "$var" # GNU printf
'TOPIC'$'\r'
$ (export var; bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$var"') # bash builtin
$'TOPIC\r'
$ (export var; ksh93 -c 'printf "%q\n" "$var"') # ksh93 builtin
$'TOPIC\r'
$ (export var; dash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$var"')
dash: 1: printf: %q: invalid directive
```

`%q` is not a standard `printf` directive, not all implementations support it, and the behaviour varies among implementations that do. `sed -n l` is a portable/standard way to get unambiguous visual representations of strings (though the output also varies between implementations):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed -n l
TOPIC\r$
```

That `$` is to show the end of the line (useful for lines that have trailing spaces).

```
$ var=${var//$'\r'}
$ printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed -n l
TOPIC$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\r` is notation inhered from C and means a Carriage Return. Your file very likely has DOS/Windows -style CRLF line endings. `sed` and `xargs` consider the CR just another character, and it gets passed through. Though anything else on the same line, outside the `<Name>...</Name>` tags would also get passed through by that sed.

```
$ echo 'foo <Name>bar</Name><Num>123</Num>' | sed 's/<Name>\([^<]*\)<\/Name>/\1/'
foo bar<Num>123</Num>
```

If you're picking fields out of an XML file like that, you may want to have the `sed` remove anything else surrounding the line at the same time:

```
$ echo 'foo <Name>bar</Name><Num>123</Num>' | sed 's/.*<Name>\([^<]*\)<\/Name>.*/\1/'
bar
```

That should get rid of any CR at the end, too, since they match the `.*`.