# How to print and insert a variable in the beginning of the file in Unix?

Tags: sed

```
Length=$(cat Final.txt|wc -l)
echo $Length
sed -i '1 i\<records>$(echo $Length)</records>' Final.txt
```

I need to the add the line XXX where XXX should be the variable which represents the no.of lines.I have tried the above code and other combinations.None of them seems to work.

Comment: single quotes don't expand anything inside them, double quotes do. Compare `echo '$Length'` and `echo "$Length"`. (Besides, the command substitution and `echo` in the `sed` command are unnecessary). shellcheck.net would actually tell you both of those.

Comment: references: [What's a good mnemonic for shell double vs. single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/170373) and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
Length=$(wc -l < Final.txt)
echo $Length
sed -i "1 i\<records>$Length</records>" Final.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "1 i\<records>$(wc -l Final.txt < Final.txt)</records>" Final.txt
```

1. You don't need an intermediate variable.
2. Edit: Per user kamaraj & per user DonChrissti's commened, removed claim that you need the `cut` command, or some other way to parse out the file name which `wc` outputs along with the number of lines. A simple I/O redirection hides that from `wc`, so without knowing what file is being processed, it has nothing to print.

Comment: <records>$(wc -l Final.txt | cut -d" " -f1)</records>   This is my output in the file. It is not working.