# unable to include inverted comma's while using an echo comand

Tags: quoting

I was trying to echo the SNMP configuration inside the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file, 
however, i noticed that it is removing "" while echoing the text inside the configuration file.....
i have tried out below ways but couldn't figure out......
Kindly help!!!!
OS: **Oracle Linux Server release 6.4**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes (either single `'` or double `"` quotes) are used to quote other special characters, like whitespace and glob characters, or other quotes:

```
$ echo "*"
*
$ echo "'"
'
$ echo '"ab""c"'
"ab""c"
```

Or you could use backslashes to escape the quotes:

```
$ echo \"abc\"
"abc"
```

The difference between single and double quotes is that within double-quotes backslashes (used for escaping other characters) and dollar signs (used for parameter expansions and command substitutions) are still special. Within single-quotes they are not.

See also

- [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) in [Greg's wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/).
- [What's a good mnemonic for shell double vs. single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)