# "sed" replace date in text file with current date

Tags: awk, sed

We want to call a parameter file (.txt) where my application read dynamic values when the job is triggered, one of such values are below:

```
abc.txt
------------------
Code:
line1
line2
line3
$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT=08-27-2019
line4
$$EDWS_PREV_DATE_INSERT=08-26-2019
```

I am trying to write a small command that can update these dates daily with current date but its not replacing the date value.
Code:

```
sed -i 's/$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT =.*/$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT="$(date `+%y%m%d`)"/' abc.txt
```

Current result:

```
$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT="$(date `+%y%m%d`)"
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

Your command has an extra space

```
sed -i 's/$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT<extra_space>=.*/$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT="$(date `+%y%m%d`)"/' abc.txt
```

I think what you are looking for is:

```
sed -i "s/\$\$EDWS_DATE_INSERT=.*/\$\$EDWS_DATE_INSERT=$(date '+%y%m%d')/" abc.txt
```

Better yet:

```
sed -E -i "s/(\\\$\\\$EDWS_DATE_INSERT=).*/\1$(date '+%y%m%d')/" abc.txt
```

Output:

```
line1
line2
line3
$$EDWS_DATE_INSERT=190827
line4
$$EDWS_PREV_DATE_INSERT=08-26-2019
```

Replace `sed`'s single quotes for double quotes.
Replacing back ticks for single quotes.

EDIT: my previous command was **wrong**. Updated with fixed command.

Comment: Don't you need to escape $s?

Comment: Importantly, replacing the "strong" single quotes with double-quotes. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/117549

Comment: @JakubJindra You are right! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use a little script for similar purpose

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_NOW=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")
echo "its: $DATE_NOW"
sed -i 's|DEV-BuildTime.*|DEV-BuildTime '"$DATE_NOW"'|' path/to/file
```

note:

- don't get the (UTC +N) in the date fearing regexp interpretation
- use the | for 's' separator (not : nor / that are present in date format)

Comment: The required format is `%y%m%d`, not `%Y/%m/%d`. What's the relevance of `DEV-BuildTime` when the question uses `$$EDWS_PREV_DATE_INSERT`?

Comment: @roaima my aim isn't to solve a 2 years old bug but to give help to people willing to solve similar problem